# Spring boot interceptor to capture request values on bean validation

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I have a spring boot app(v2.3.0.RELEASE) and I need to get any request being sent from my restcontroller when there is a bean validation error.

My Request is as follows:

```
public class PaymentRequest {
    @Valid
    private PaymentIdentificationRequest paymentIdentification;
    @NotBlank(message = "transactionTypeCode.required")
    private String transactionTypeCode;
    @NotBlank(message = "name.required")
    private String name;
```

}

For instance, if name is null, I need an interceptor to capture values of transactionTypeCode and
paymentIdentification before exception is triggered.

I tried implementing the following interceptor to capture all not null parameters value being sent:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest requestServlet, HttpServletResponse responseServlet, Object handler) throws Exception {
       

//capture required valued set it in HttpServletRequest attribute to be used for exception handling
        HandlerMethod h1 = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        MethodParameter[] param = null;


        System.out.println("MINIMAL: INTERCEPTOR PREHANDLE CALLED");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        Enumeration<?> e = request.getParameterNames();
        System.out.println("MINIMAL: INTERCEPTOR POSTHANDLE CALLED");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception) throws Exception {
        Enumeration<?> e = request.getParameterNames();
        System.out.println("MINIMAL: INTERCEPTOR AFTERCOMPLETION CALLED");
    }
```

When the name is null it enters the method preHandle but I am not able to get the parameters and its corresponding values being sent, any idea how to do it pls?

The reason why I am doing the above changes is because I need to set the value of transactionTypeCode and paymentIdentification in my interceptor above so as to use them below in my exception handler as follows:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
       private @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

@Override
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception, HttpHeaders headers,
                                                           HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);

// mapParam  is size zero 
Map<String, String[]> mapParam = httpServletRequest.getParameterMap();
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(exception) && !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(this.request1)) {
            paymentValidator.onErrorUpdatePayment(this.request1.getAttribute("transactionTypeCode"), this.request1.getAttribute("paymentIdentification "), exception.toString());
        }

    ....
    return new ResponseEntity<>(ipsResponse, new HttpHeaders(), ipsResponse.getHttpStatus());
}
```

Comment: Why? What is it you are trying to achieve? In the `preHandle` nothing is validated yet. What is it you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated my question, basically I have an exception handler method and I need values from my request in my exception handler method for further processing. I thought that If I set the values in HttpServletRequest attribute from the interceptor then I can use them in my exception handler.

Comment: You don't need an interceptor for that, you can do that directly in your handler. You can just use the `HttpServletRequest` no need for an interceptor. You are making things more complex then needed.

Comment: Thnks for the quick response, I have tried to autowire  HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest in my exceptionhandler but no parameter is available since the httpServletRequest.getParameterMap() is zero. I have updated the question with the above code.

Comment: You already have it in yourmethod the `WebRequest`  is what you need. Are you actually sending parameters or a request body?

Comment: oh I am currently sending request body from my rest controller and method signature is ResponseEntity<PaymentResponse> validatePayment(@Valid @RequestBody InstantPaymentRequest instantPaymentRequest)

Comment: So then why would parameters be filled if you aren't sending parameters but a request body...

Comment: My apologies I missed that, is it possible to get the request body?

Comment: As mentioned you have the `WebRequest` you can do with that what ever you like.